# Responsive navigation menu Toggle'n

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I want my responsive navigation to toggle, the code below just expand the Menu button to the different pages. I want to toggle it, so now it just expand but not fold it in.

HTML:

> ```
>   <nav>
>       <a  href="#footer_nav" >&#9776;  MENU</a>
>       <ul>
>           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Opleiding</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Onderwijsprogramma</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Organisatie</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Stages en projecten</a></li>
>       </ul>
>   </nav>
> ```

CSS:

> .in-visible {
>       display: none;
>       list-style: none;
>       margin-left: 0;
>       padding-left: 0;
>       margin-bottom: 0; }
>
> .visible {
>       display: block; }

Javascript:

> var responsivenav = document.querySelector('header > nav > ul');
>
> responsivenav.classList.add('in-visible');
>
> document.querySelector('header > nav > a').onclick = function(){
>     responsivenav.classList.add('visible'); }

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Can you use jQuery in your project?

Comment: No, preferably Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **[toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)** method instead of the add method.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/szt9zhL5/)

```
var responsivenav = document.querySelector('nav > ul');

responsivenav.classList.add('in-visible');

document.querySelector('nav > a').onclick = function() { 
    responsivenav.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```